# Unable to find the reason for this: bash missing'

Tags: bash

why am I getting "**bash missing'**" for this:

```
function get_xserver ()
{
    case $TERM in
        xterm )
            XSERVER=$(who am i | awk '{print $NF}' | tr -d ')''(' )
            ;;
            aterm | rxvt)
            # Find some code that works here. ...
            ;;
    esac
}
```

This is the exact error:

```
bash: [: missing `]'
```

Comment: Please provide the **exact** error message, copied-and-pasted.

Comment: ...I'm also unable to reproduce that function definition, on its own, causing the issue at hand; please ensure that your question is sufficiently complete.

Comment: Irrelevant, but you don't have to quote the parentheses separately; `tr -d ')('` would work fine.

Comment: This is the exact error: `bash: [: missing `]'`

Comment: Tried quoting the parentheses separately but still got the same.

Comment: As dimo says with their entirely correct answer, your problem is caused by something not at all found in the same code you put into your question. In the future, test that the code in the question is sufficient to reproduce an issue before posting.

Comment: Also, when providing extra information about your problem, that should be edited into the question, not added as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not in the code you posted. The error message:

> ```
> -bash: [: missing `]'
> ```

Means exactly what it says - there is a missing `]` character, namely in a `[ test ]` statement.

Try it:

```
$ [ 1 -eq 2
-bash: [: missing `]'
```

You need to identify where the error *actually* is, and add the missing closing bracket.

Comment: OK ... I finally tracked it down. Thanks so much!